# Is there a service that shows you the favorite tweets of the people you follow?

Tags: webapp-rec, twitter

I'm looking for something like [Stellar](http://stellar.io) but already populated with the people I'm following.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Favstar's [Tweets recently faved by people you follow](http://favstar.fm/tweets-recently-faved-by-people-you-follow)

This will you give a list of the most recently Starred Tweets. Unfortunately there is a limit to how much you can see per day based on their [Bonus Features](https://favstar.fm/en/bonus_features?c=m)

You can also try making a [favstar.fm list](http://favstar.fm/recent-tweets-by-my-favstar-fm-list)

Answer (score 0):

Check your [Activity list](https://twitter.com/#!/activity) on Twitter. It contains

- Starred Tweets
- Recent Follows
- Recent List Changes

Comment: yes it does, but it contains too much info, there's too much focus required of my part to just follow the Starred Tweets - which renders it useless - for me at least.